# If statement does not work as intended in java

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, methods

I am trying to create a method that basically takes `int` values from an array of objects and checks which object is closer to a specific value. I have done this while using numerous `if statements` and so far the method doesn't print an outcome.

I have written this code as shown below while trying to make this work properly.

```
public void teamlengthaverage(int N) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (teams[i].getScore() <= mesoScore(N)) {
            for (int j = 0; j != i && j < N; j++) {
                if (teams[i].getScore() > teams[j].getScore()) {
                    System.out.print(
                            "The team closest to the average score is: "
                                    + teams[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (teams[i].getScore() >= mesoScore(N)) {
            for (int j = 0; j != i && j < N; j++) {
                if (teams[i].getScore() < teams[j].getScore()) {
                    System.out.print(
                            "The team closest to the average score is: "
                                    + teams[i]);

                    /*
                     * the program checks if a value above or below the
                     * value of mesoScore is closer to it while also
                     * different to other values in the array as well
                     */
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The IDE isn't showing me any errors. Not even a warning for the code so I cannot find the issue specifically. If anyone has an idea to what is wrong with this please comment or answer.

Comment: As a basic debugging step, put `println` statements before each conditional check, that output the values of all referenced variables as well as the result of the condition. You'll quickly find which values aren't what you think they should be, which will lead to the problem. (Or learn to use a debugger, either way's fine.)

Comment: If your doing `j< N` in your loop to you really want to compare to `mesoScore(N)`?  It would also help if you would post a [mre] that compiles and runs.  And including any data and expected output.  We can't run a lone method with no enclosing class and test data.

Comment: "The IDE isn't showing me any errors" that's because you've written _valid_ code, just not the particular instance of valid code that will do what you want. Compilers can't tell you what you've done wrong, merely whether it compiles.

Comment: It would also *really* help if you asked your IDE to indent your code. At the moment several statements are indented in a very counter-intuitive way.

Comment: I also strongly suggest that you always use `{}` for if blocks and looping blocks even if the block contains just a single statement.  It has the potential to save lots of debugging time in the future.  And also use print statements to print various values throughout your program to help assess what  is going on.   Printing is the first step towards debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that it's not the `if`, it's the `for` that's not working as you expect:

```
for(int j = 0; j != i && j<N; j++)
```

This will break immediately on the first iteration because `j == i` (== 0). A `for` loop only executes while the condition is true: it stops immediately when the condition is false.

It doesn't carry on speculatively looking for another value for which the condition might be true again - in general, there may be no such value.

I suspect that you mean instead:

```
for(int j = 0; j<N; j++) {
  if (j == i) continue;

  // ...
}
```

which skips over the case where `j == i`, but continues after.

Comment: I tried what you have said is the answer to my problem but still no luck. I tried changing the method to include the variable that you get from mesoScore(N) and I still did not get a valid answer for my problem. Still thanks for the answer as it gets me closer to a solution

Comment: @WJS I added brackets to the code here and at the src but I don't exactly understand what you exactly mean in your first comment and would appreciate if you could elaborate as to what is wrong with the second loops and mesoScore(N).

Comment: Apparently the problem was that the compiler wouldn't work with only two teams but even with three teams the program still gives me headaches in the form of console wizardry. What I'm trying to say is when i run the program it returns this weird thing `lab02.TD@300ffa5d`. What is this and how do I solve it?

Comment: "Apparently the problem was that the compiler wouldn't work with only two teams but even with three teams the program still gives me headaches in the form of console wizardry." The compiler works fine with two teams. And what is "console wizardry"?

Comment: "What is this and how do I solve it?" That's the default implementation of `Object.toString()`: it's the name of the class, an `@`, and the hashcode. Look up how to override `toString()`.